No pipe found with name 'isNull'. <span>{{ apiData.Name | isNull }}</span> [Angular 7 Code Base Directly Bumped to Angular 18]
Angular 18 Pipe Unknown
Earlier code was working with Angular 7,
but then I Have Bumped up Angular Version and Related dependencies Directly to 18 Using npm install and ng update and solved other dependency issue. what is causing custom pipe to not work.
I Have checked all possible aspect like Import in Telecom module, Export from Shared module.
By Angular Concept TelecomDetailsComponent Wll get all Modules, Utilities, Pipes, Models which are exported by that individual module and imported by Telecom.module.ts. so i should get access to isNull Pipe. but I am not getting desired result.
Telecom-Details.component.html
No pipe found with name 'isNull'. {{ apiData.name | isNull }}
Shared.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NullCheck } from '../helper/null-check.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NullCheck
  ],
  imports: [
   
  ],
  exports: [
   NullCheck
  ]})
export class SharedModule { }


null.check.pipe.ts
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'isNull',
})
export class NullCheck implements PipeTransform {

   transform(items:any): String {
     if (!items) {
       return '-';
     }
     return items;
    }
  
}


telecom.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { TelecomDetailsComponent } from './telecom-details/telecom-details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TelecomDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TelecomRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class TelecomModule { }

I Have Gone through the workflow of Angular Dependency management. like Pipe has imported in SharedModule and exported as well. Shared module imported in TelecomModule. and TelecomDetailComponent is Declared in TelecomModule.
